# Как правильно произносить фамилию Фоллет? Куда ставить ударение?

Tags: орфоэпия, фамилии

Как правильно произносить фамилию писательницы Барбары Фоллетт? ФоллЕт или фОллетт? Куда ставить ударение?

Comment: Такая же по написанию фамилия современного писателя из Уэльса (Ken Follett) произносится с ударением на _первом_ слоге (ФОллет) - это ясно из интервью на ютюбе. В связи с безударностью второго слога, при транскрипции не стоит сохранять второе "т" - оно и вызывает сомнения в произношении.

Answer (score 1):

Словарь английских фамилий Рыбакина дает Follett — Фоллетт с ударением на первом слоге. Ударение на "о".